# gTTS (Google-Text-to-Speech) Error: Audio gets saved but only play after opening the groovy app

Tags: python, google-text-to-speech

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os

mytext = 'Welcome to the hub!'

language = 'en'

myobj = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)

myobj.save("welcome.mp3")

os.system("welcome.mp3")
```

The above is my code! im trying to make a smart speaker for eg google home.

My problem is when the last line is ran `os.system("welcome.mp3")` i dont want it to open the groovy app to say the audio. I want it to just reply within the terminal is that possible?

EDIT: i have disbanded this project however if you want to do something similar to this id recommend the `winsound` module. Id assume that it is however only for windows

Answer (score 0):

if you want to directly play the song , you can use python playsound module:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('welcome.mp3')
```

other os module uses your default media player , you can mention the program you want the mp3 be played with before the file name,
there is a terminal sound player for terminal in linux called `mpg123` you can use :

```
# apt install mpg123
os.system("mpg123 " + file)
```